# How to visualize Hash data structure in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, graph, dot

I have a hash object, whose structure looks similar to this:

```
{:category1 => 
 {:subcategory1 => 
  [ 
   {:article => "some article", :date => "2010-04-04"},
   ...
  ],
  :subc2 => [...] 
 },
 :category2 => {...},
 ...
}
```

How can I visualize it as graph in ruby?

Is there a simple method/gem/lib that converts this Hash to DOT?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with DOT. Could you expand that out please?

Comment: My guess: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language

Comment: Yes, DOT - graph description language -  this is what I was talking about.

Comment: using pp doesn't cut it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use the [ruby-graphviz gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-graphviz) for this sort of visualization.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want it to be a graph? The data in your example is a tree.

You can see the tree easily in text with Ruby's pretty print:

```
pp my_hash
```

If you want a little cleaner output:

```
puts my_hash.to_yaml
```